# Safe way to dynamic cast void to a type?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

My C++ is a bit rusty and I don't remember everything in the standard.

I have a `void*`. In one specific function it is either a class that inherits Alpha or one that inherits Beta. Both base classes have virtual functions. However I can't seem to tell which is which

```
class Alpha {
public:
    virtual void Speak() { printf("A"); }
};
class Beta {
public:
    virtual void Speak() { printf("B"); }
};
int main(){
    //BAD CODE WILL PRINT TWICE
    void *p = new Alpha;
    Alpha*a = dynamic_cast<Alpha*>((Alpha*)p);
    Beta*b = dynamic_cast<Beta*>((Beta*)p);
    if(a)
        a->Speak();
    if(b)
        b->Speak();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I figure out which class is which? There are 100's of classes in this codebase that gets converted to void. Most of them inherit 5 base classes however I'm not eager to find out. Is the only solution inheriting from something like `class Dummy {public: virtual void NoOp(){}};` and cast to Dummy before using dynamic cast? Is this safe? I'm hoping there's a better solution but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: You can't because `dynamic_cast` uses `rtti` to determine if a type relates to another. In your code `Alpha` doesn't relate to `Beta` nor `void` to either. Is there a real problem you're trying to solve or is this just academic?

Comment: There is no way to discover what a `void*` actually points to, and `dynamic_cast<Beta*>((Beta*)p)` has the same effect as `(Beta*)p`.

Comment: Pass the correct enum value... `enum WhatType { kUnknown, kAlpha, kBeta };` ...along with the `void*` and use that to discriminate what kind of pointer is in hand.

Comment: *"There are 100's of classes in this codebase that gets converted to void. Most of them inherit 5 base classes"* - bring the Flammenwerfer!

Comment: @Eljay: Can't C++ look at the vtable address?

Comment: The vtable address is an implementation detail, and may not exist at all.

Comment: @QuickQuestion even if you assume a vtable implementation, you still cannot check whether your `void*` points to a valid vpointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *only* thing you can do with a `void*` pointer is to cast it back to *exactly* the same type as the pointer that was cast to `void*` in the first place. The behaviour on doing **anything** else is undefined.

What you could do in your case is define

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual ~Base() = default; // make me a polymorphic type and make 
                               // polymorphic delete safe at the same time.
};
```

and make this the base class for `Alpha` and `Beta`. Then pass a `Base*` pointer around rather than a `void*` one, and take your `dynamic_cast`s directly on `p`.

Note further that if you declared `virtual void Speak() = 0;` in `Base`, then your code in `main` would become simply

```
int main(){ 
    Base* p = new Alpha;
    p->Speak();
    delete p; // ToDo - have a look at std::unique_ptr
}
```

As a rule of thumb, casts of any kind are undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `Alpha*a = dynamic_cast<Alpha*>((Alpha*)p);` first casts `p` to `Alpha*` with an [explicit c style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). Then, that resulting `Alpha*` is passed through `dynamic_cast<Alpha*>`. Using `dynamic_cast<T*>` on a `T*` pointer (a pointer of the same type as you are trying to cast to) will always provide the input pointer. It cannot be used to confirm that the pointer is valid. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for `dynamic_cast<new_type>(expression)` :

> If the type of `expression` is exactly `new_type` or a less cv-qualified version of `new_type`, the result is the value of `expression`, with type `new_type`.

As a result, the code will always compile and run and the type system will not protect you. But the resulting behavior is undefined. In the case of `Beta*b = dynamic_cast<Beta*>((Beta*)p);` you tell the compiler to trust that `p` is a `Beta*` but this is not true. Dereferencing the resulting pointer is undefined behavior  and `dynamic_cast` cannot protect you from this mistake.

If you try to remove the explicit type conversion, you will get a compiler error. `dynamic_cast` requires a pointer or reference to a complete type, and `void` is not a complete type. You will have to find a way to track the actual type pointed to yourself and explicitly convert `p` to that pointer type before using `dynamic_cast`. Though at that point, if you already know the type to cast to, it may no longer be necessary.

Consider using a common base type instead or maybe using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a C-style cast to convert to `Alpha*`, similar to a static_cast before using dynamic cast, then the dynamic cast as no effect. here your code runs because the two classes have the same interface but in reality this is undefined behaviour.

Usually, you want to use dynamic cast to upcast/downcast from/to a base class to/from it's derived class.

For example, if we add a base interface, then convert the `void *` pointer to this base class and then use dynamic cast to attempt Up-casting, the code works as expected and only print once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Speaker {
public:
  virtual void Speak() = 0;
};

class Alpha: public Speaker {
public:
  virtual void Speak() { printf("A"); }
};

class Beta: public Speaker {
public:
  virtual void Speak() { printf("B"); }
};

int main(){
  void *p = new Alpha;
  // Convert to base type, using static_cast                                    
  Speaker *s = static_cast<Speaker *>(p);
  // Attempt Upcasts                                                            
  Alpha*a = dynamic_cast<Alpha*>(s);
  Beta*b = dynamic_cast<Beta*>(s);

  // See if it worked                                                           
  if (a)
    a->Speak();
  if (b)
    b->Speak();
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs: `A`

Answer (score 0):

You must know the type from which the void pointer was converted from. If you don't know the dynamic type, then you must create the void pointer from the pointer to base. If you don't know the type of the pointer which the void pointer was created from, then you cannot use the void pointer.

Given that the void pointer was converted from `Alpha*`, you can convert it back using a static cast:

```
auto a_ptr = static_cast<Alpha*>(p);
```

You can then use `dynamic_cast` to convert to a derived type.

```
if(auto d_ptr = dynamic_cast<DerivedAlpha*>(a_ptr)) {
    // do stuff with DerivedAlpha
```

In case the dynamic type isn't `DerivedAlpha`, the dynamic cast would safely return null. You cannot dynamic cast away from a type hierarchy. Since `Alpha` and `Beta` are not related by any inheritance structure, they cannot be dynamically casted mutually.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this could be explained more simply than what is said already.

Basically, casting from a raw void*, none of the "smarts" of dynamic_cast can apply because it has nothing to go on, it just gives you back the same pointer. You need to have some shared parent class type or something as your pointer type (*p) so it knows how to read the memory and determine actual type.

In your case, you are "lucking out" that the memory layout of Alpha and Beta is the same so calling speak on Beta* ends up calling Alpha::speak(). As others said this is UB and if the classes were more different you would likely seg-fault or corrupt the stack.